# How do I make a Discord bot that tags someone?

Tags: discord.py, bots

I just can't figure it out. What do I do?

```
    if message.channel.name == "general":
        if user_message.lower() == "do it jeff":
            await message.channel.send(f"My name is Jeff @Someone")
            return
```

Answer (score -1):

message.author.username pulls the display name from the sender, while message.author.id will pull their discord ID

So in your case try:

```
 if message.channel.name == "general":
        if user_message.lower() == "do it jeff":
            await message.channel.send(f"My name is Jeff @"message.author.username)
//I use javascript for my bots and do message.channel.send(`My name is Jeff @${message.author.username}`) not exactly sure about python 
            return
```